# Is it possible to have a function without a parameter in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql

I am being forced to put a @noparameter varchar(1)=null in this function?
How do I create a function to return a table which has no parameters!

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DropDownIndividuals](@noparameter varchar(1)=null)
RETURNS
    @IndividualsList TABLE(
          Case_Number VARCHAR(11)
         ,LastName    VARCHAR(100)
         ,FirstName   VARCHAR(100)
         ,Midlename   VARCHAR(100)
         ,FullName    VARCHAR(100) 
        )
AS  
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @IndividualsList
       SELECT DISTINCT
       cast(Case_Number as varchar(10))as Case_Number
      ,[Lastname]
      ,[Firstname]
      ,[Middlename]
      ,rtrim([Lastname]+ ' '+ [Firstname]) as FullName
      FROM [MHMODSSQL1P].[ODS].[dbo].[Contact]
      WHERE [LastName] is not null and [FirstName] is not null
      UNION ALL SELECT null,null,null,null,null
      ORDER BY [LastName]

      RETURN 

END;
```

Comment: There is no reason to insert the data into a temp table just to retun it. Return it directly or even better write a View.

Comment: @Mangus: Strictly speaking, it doesn't look like he's returning *anything*.

Comment: Friendly note... it isn't necessary to prepend your title with tags.

Comment: @Adam actually it is the correct syntax for a Table-Valued UDF. But it wuld be better to write an inline UDF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294.aspx

Comment: @Mangus: My mistake; you're right. In any case, it actually seems like a view would be better than an inline-udf in this case, since there are no parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[DropDownIndividuals]()
```

You can just use open and close brackets to define function without parameters, Assuming you are using SQL server.

Answer (score 5):

You should be a able to do it with something like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DropDownIndividuals]()
```

But since a table-valued function is essentially a parameterised view, you might as well just [use a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) rather than a TVF with no parameters:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DropDownIndividuals]
AS
SELECT -- etc
```

Comment: Is a matter of finding it easily with the other functions. We want to look only in one place to find all our needs.

Comment: @user475337: There are *big* performance differences between views and TVF's. If what you're doing can be done (sanely) with standard, non-procedural SQL, then you *really should* use a view.

Comment: @Adam Robinson,@user475337: this kind of TVF is bad. An inline TVF is the same as a view.

Answer (score 1):

As Sachin quite rightly gave the answer:

`FUNCTION [dbo].[DropDownIndividuals]()`

It's important to note that even though the function doesn't have parameters, you should still call the function with empty parentheses, else you'll get an error such as [The multi-part identifier "dbo.DropDownIndividuals" could not be found].

```
SELECT dbo.DropDownIndividuals()
```

Comment: -1: there are no parameters in your `SELECT` statement, only empty parentheses.

Comment: That's exactly my point!! Even though there are no parameters in the function, unless you enter empty parentheses when calling in a View, an error will be returned!

Comment: That's because it's a "function".