# how to call scalar function in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a Scalar Functions, it was created successfully, but when I call the function using select statement, it says  Invalid object name 'dbo.fun_functional_score'.

my function:

```
 ALTER function [dbo].[fun_functional_score] (@phy_id varchar(20))
 returns  varchar(50)

as
begin 

declare @level_initial int, @level_current int

-- initial functional score
set @level_initial=(SELECT pflag.fun_level
FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
    inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
WHERE phy.Physicion_id=@phy_id
    and pflag.visited_count=(select MAX(visited_count)-1 from tbl_all_purple_flag_level ))


-- current functional score
set @level_current=(SELECT pflag.fun_level
FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
    inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
WHERE phy.Physicion_id=@phy_id
    and pflag.visited_count=(select MAX(visited_count) from tbl_all_purple_flag_level ))


--to calculate functional score
declare @fun_level varchar(20),@result varchar(50)

set  @fun_level=@level_current-@level_initial;

 if @fun_level = 0   set @result='Maintained' 
if @fun_level = '-1'  set @result='Minor Improvement' 
if @fun_level = '-2'  set @result='Moderate Improvement' 
if @fun_level = '-3'  set @result='Significant Improvement' 
if @fun_level =  '-4'  set @result='Substantial Improvement' 
if @fun_level =  '1'  set @result='Minor Reduction' 
if @fun_level =  '2'  set @result='Moderate Reduction' 
if @fun_level =  '3'  set @result='Significant Reduction' 
if @fun_level =  '4'  set @result='Substantial Reduction' 




return @result

end
```

i used this select to call

```
 select * from dbo.fun_functional_score('01091400003') as [er]
```

or

```
 select * from dbo.fun_functional_score('01091400003')
```

both showing error "Invalid object name 'dbo.fun_functional_score'.
"

where i made error . can anyone help me...

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Your syntax is for table valued function which return a resultset and can be queried like a table. For scalar function do

```
 select  dbo.fun_functional_score('01091400003') as [er]
```

Comment: Must specify the schema as shown, not just the function name. I had to retry several times due to this. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 27):

You have a scalar valued function as opposed to a table valued function. The from clause is used for tables. Just query the value directly in the column list.

```
select dbo.fun_functional_score('01091400003')
```

Answer (score 9):

For some reason I was not able to use my scalar function until I referenced it using brackets, like so:

```
select [dbo].[fun_functional_score]('01091400003')
```

Comment: See that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995442/is-it-possible-to-have-a-function-without-a-parameter-in-t-sql It seems that the same applies when there are parameters

Answer (score 3):

For ***Scalar Function*** Syntax is

```
Select dbo.Function_Name(parameter_name)

Select dbo.Department_Employee_Count('HR')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the top answer and it still doesn't work, then there may be something wrong with the function.  In my case, the function referred to a table that didn't exist anymore, and instead of the error message telling me what was really happening, it just gave me the same error message as above.