# How to execute function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I build a function and I am trying to execute it...but some errors are occurring

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Afisho_rankimin(@emri_rest int)
RETURNS int
AS
   BEGIN
       Declare @rankimi int
       Select @rankimi=dbo.RESTORANTET.Rankimi
       From RESTORANTET
       Where  dbo.RESTORANTET.ID_Rest=@emri_rest
       RETURN @rankimi
  END
  GO
    SELECT dbo.Afisho_rankimin(5)AS Rankimi
  GO
```

The errors when I execute it are:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure Afisho_rankimin, Line 11
>   There is already an object named 'Afisho_rankimin' in the database.

and also it is said that:

> Can not find column "dbo", or the user defined function, or aggregate "dbo.Afisho_rankimin", or the name is ambiguous

Comment: Do you have another object with that name of a different type? Look in sys.objects for something with that name.

Answer (score 37):

It looks like there's something else called `Afisho_rankimin` in your DB so the function is not being created. Try calling your function something else. E.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Afisho_rankimin1(@emri_rest int)
RETURNS int
AS
   BEGIN
       Declare @rankimi int
       Select @rankimi=dbo.RESTORANTET.Rankimi
       From RESTORANTET
       Where  dbo.RESTORANTET.ID_Rest=@emri_rest
       RETURN @rankimi
  END
  GO
```

Note that you need to call this only once, not every time you call the function. After that try calling

```
SELECT dbo.Afisho_rankimin1(5) AS Rankimi
```

Comment: Looks like the select is raising an error that there is no such function though.

Comment: I see apparently there's something else called that name. Will revise the answer

Comment: I also tried with `SELECT myfunctionname .......` but it is giving me error as `Invalid column name`

Answer (score 26):

I have come to this question and the one below several times.

[how to call scalar function in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21041345/153923)

Each time, I try entering the Function using the syntax shown here in SQL Server Management Studio, or SSMS, to see the results, and each time I get the errors.

For me, that is because my result set is in tabular data format. Therefore, to see the results in SSMS, I have to call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Afisho_rankimin_TABLE(5);
```

I understand that the author's question involved a scalar function, so this answer is only to help others who come to StackOverflow often when they have a problem with a query (like me).

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 3):

you may be create function before so,
update your function again using.

```
Alter FUNCTION dbo.Afisho_rankimin(@emri_rest int)
RETURNS int
AS
  BEGIN
     Declare @rankimi int
     Select @rankimi=dbo.RESTORANTET.Rankimi
     From RESTORANTET
     Where  dbo.RESTORANTET.ID_Rest=@emri_rest
     RETURN @rankimi
END
GO

SELECT dbo.Afisho_rankimin(5) AS Rankimi
GO
```

Comment: This is dangerous advice if the originally created function is for something different and was perhaps even created by someone else. You should never alter a function or stored proc or table or view unless you already know exactly what it does.