# I have a scalar function in a SQL Server database which I want to to call using ADO.NET but it always returns null

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a scalar function that returns one value in SQL Server. I'm trying to get that value by calling `ExecuteScalar`, but it always returns NULL and C# throws a `NullReferenceException`.

I created a function that checks room availability; if the room is available, it should return the `roomId`, otherwise `0`.

I'm calling that function in C# using ADO.NET, but in this case, it throws an exception.

ADO.NET code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "RoomAvailability";

    con.Open();

    int returnValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    // The error happens on this line
    Console.WriteLine(returnValue.ToString());
}
```

SQL Server scalar function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION RoomAvailability()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @availability INT

    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Romm_Details WHERE status = 'F')
    BEGIN
        SET @availability = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Romm_Details WHERE status = 'F')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @availability = 0
    END

    RETURN @availability    //RETURN NULL VALUE 
END
```

Expected result :

- if room available return room Id
- else return 0

Comment: Probably, you should accept an answer if its solves your problem just as a vote of thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a scalar udf, it is possible to use CommandType.StoredProcedure, but you need to add a ReturnValue parameter to get the result. e.g.:

```
        var command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "RoomAvailability";

        con.Open();

        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@res", SqlDbType.Int);
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(p);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int returnValue = (int)p.Value;
```

Or alternatively, use the technique using CommandType.Text (the default CommandType) as described in Bharathi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change how you invoke the [SQL Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) from C#.

1. Remove `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` - you are invoking a function and not a stored procedure
2. You cannot invoke a SQL function just by its [name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041345/how-to-call-scalar-function-in-sql-server-2008) (like a stored procedure), you will need to use it as an inline query

   ```
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.RoomAvailability()", con);
        con.Open();
        int returnValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

        Console.WriteLine(returnValue.ToString());
    }
   ```